# Select empty value in dropdown list with jQuery if not contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am trying to select the empty (first) value of a dropdown select option if it does not contains the value from an another dropdown select list:

```
$('#FirstDropdown').change(function() {
    if ( $('#SecondDropdown option').filter(':contains(' + this.value  + ')') ){
        $('#SecondDropdown option').filter(':contains(' + this.value  + ')').prop('selected',true);
    }else{
        $("#SecondDropdown option[value='']").prop('selected',true);
    }
});
```

This code work well if `#SecondDropdown option` contains `this.value` but the else statement doesn't reset the dropdown list if not.

Any suggestion please ?

EDIT : The dropdown lists look like this :

```
<select id="FirstDropdown">
    <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="VAL1">First Value</option>
    <option value="VAL2">Second Value</option>
    <option value="VAL3">Third Value</option>
    <option value="VAL4">Fourth Value</option>
</select>

<select id="SecondDropdown">
    <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="12">VAL1 SELECT OPTION</option>
    <option value="15">VAL2 SELECT OPTION</option>
    <option value="10">VAL3 SELECT OPTION</option>
</select>
```

EDIT : Added a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSo/c4uo6uad/).

Comment: please share the markup

Comment: I don't understand. You want the HTML sources ?

Comment: yes. html for select elements

Comment: I have édited my question to add a JsFiddle. And to show why I need to evaluate the value with "containts" filter. Sorry for omission

Comment: posted the new answer below. check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70195/discussion-between-mrso-and-milind-anantwar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :There is problem in your `if` condition as it is getting always true. You can use `.length` to check if `option` exist and select the option else select blank

```
$('#FirstDropdown').change(function() {
    if ($('#SecondDropdown option:contains('+this.value +')').length>0){
        $('#SecondDropdown option:contains('+this.value +')').prop('selected',true);
    }else{
        $("#SecondDropdown option[value='-1']").prop('selected',true);
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c4uo6uad/23/)**

Comment: The if statement works well in my question. I have to evaluate the content with the jQuery filter contains. And this work well. But not in the else statement.

Comment: can you try `$("#SecondDropdown option[value=]").prop('selected',true);` in else statement. Please share your html with `select` options code

Comment: please have a look over edited answer (for else part)

Comment: Thanks. but this don't work. You still trying to evaluate the first condition. And this is not where is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any option element having `value=''`. You need to use `$("#SecondDropdown option[value='-1']").prop('selected',true);` . you would also need to change the condition in if statement to `this.value!=''`:

```
$('#FirstDropdown').change(function() {
  if (  this.value!='' ){
    $('#SecondDropdown option').filter(':contains(' + this.value  + ')').prop('selected',true);
}else{
    $("#SecondDropdown option[value='-1']").prop('selected',true);
}});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: @Milid Anantwar Thanks for this. It works well if I select the first option that contains blank value. I have edited my question cause in my case the first dropdown may contains values that could not be in the second dropdown. Sorry for omission

Comment: then using your old if statement should work for you

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/1v5k9v8z/) will work for you.
First, you have to check you `this.value`, because any string contains `''`.
Second, as `if` works fine, you just need to filter `option`s by `[value=-1]`

Final JS:

```
$('#FirstDropdown').change(function() {
    var $second = $('#SecondDropdown option').filter(':contains(' + this.value  + ')');
    if (this.value && $second){
        $second.prop('selected',true);
    }else{
        $("#SecondDropdown option[value=-1]").prop('selected',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: As Milind Anantwar wrote, this work well when selection the "-1" value. Can you please read again my question. I have edited because I need to evalute the "Not contains" condition. Thanks for helping